# c++20 compile time string utility

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++20

While upgrading some meta-program running in production for years to the latest (c++20) standard, I rewrote this particular compile time string utility.

Even though this new version produces desired output and correctly evaluates at compile time as well as dynamically, it's difficult to get a grasp on a new standard as always.

This example is sufficient for my particular use case. And for now I can only spot three inconsistencies I'd like to improve: two of them are marked in the code snippet with TODO, and the third one is tiding it up with concepts (like convertable_to, which is deliberately omitted in the code for simplicity sake)

I'm looking for a general case advice on how this code can be improved further.
Any other weighted criticism will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE: [New question with all of the suggestions integrated](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272488/253256)**

**Original code:**

[Live @godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXAEx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApJIBCZ86SX1kBPAMqN0AYVS0AriwYhJADlIXABk8BkwAOW8AI0xiEABOQIAHVAVCRwZ3Lx89VPSHAVDwqJZY%2BKSbTDtChiECJmICbO9fAKqazPrGgmLImLjEwIUGppbcrhtR3rD%2BssGkgEobVE9iZHYOMwBmPCoGLCoAagBZbAAVAEEAfSFzgCUASQiAcWuACWvn12C5ABFsH8TBpLjtDrNThcbncnq8Pl8Ij9/oDgaCQTswsgvFgjiZtq5kCN0Ic8dhURiGFjPDi8a4xMASIQECxSeTJLtKdjMLj8VRPJTamJWej2ZiuTzXARPMl6MK0ZdmGwFMkmBsjmwGuSAOyWdEggiYFgypgGiVEkAgdIAL0w1wIRwicpGxE89iOzrCwDxuvlaAYI0wqmSxCOTE8RCORGuHqMED9I1D4dQZgAbEcwslw4tcTqjsRMFLiAx3QRiJ6IBms96c0C9Zd4wagyGwxG/aICHGBAmW8nJCmAHSD9MMTMEbMmXP5wvFmPACBR2cVkdZwf9xbVie1%2BUGo0GU2082WvA2u0Op2l1322fan1HO9HZAIRpHaqGhQmACs5kdH6B2x9qL3kcAD0wElmWsbjtsfxHFg9AGt6gH3ou465q%2BLDvl%2BERHAAtEcXCfjBeIwWAWwfq4GikRuWowaBRyeEo6BHPwIauFcMHAJ4eA4ixkbSvQCj9g%2BhikfaADu3JMAAbqg3FHKg0TaJgboNi69iZJGCBxJgeIAGLkiCQENoGwbgeWDYPk%2BIYQKmCjrlhhHroZ94TreQHIQQ6AWmgyQAJ7XAwEAKKQDohQQCB4AoOGkuhdmIc5d6bgZlxGV2jamYuFnXvijrbNgRw2X2dlOSlLk6kh7kll5KCoH5AVBf2sUhREYURVFMX0Bh67/hVNbJal/rpSGmVpVVFqNMQTC%2BbSj6NM1pIFbZiwlUBrm9UBh4%2Bf5gWCegJpMBAyyhZpkXRXlsXdW5iU0b1vU7sa%2B74oe1q2gQq4OngcoDQGTZHDJcnXFtnaDWZRi0hEn15YtfbvZWY4rWVV3uT2Rz5DyMGxfFpWVVAaPEWNNV1YFcONZ1wUfbh%2BEhfky0haul3rfeABUePQUcGhY6tN11t9Q2g3OFk9qmsPLmOeaYAAjlx%2BYKAVL2oFQq5LqOUH5VwCPXUjG2eRaYQyQA1pgNlfuFkWEcD3ZJsLQ52Q%2BaUmSGrkne1eWA7VvkNYOl01mFqDRqW5Zw4s9Oc2VW53YaD3crS917tH%2BIEL5ySMKwmCrgtifJ4q3J%2Bg0sxkJGScp2w73nF997Gb9I0g7nTD57S5zp3lqbDirt3lQl7mHkwyQyh7n7mKbmF/Bb9pCzDNvZpXplO0PZ3YG7fnzn7i52SH/4%2B63VY9Z3SU8xX9u/SjtVxCaJC4hYBWC1bfZ5ggtsNu3Wv3lOazFm2JoQEzQ8hcQ98M7vbm8peYO3ksnSaRAQwWVmsQJmBUp6jSdq/IsL4ybUXDjdHe25I5xwPDrI8J57S5XytXBMMDoYpnst%2BRyvV5783BqyLBqJY4mh0k9fBL1TzEP5qPAmE0pozSsvNZut8g60IWtlVwxCsaolIWPG%2BA4hxiM7nQyRUB5ZUGXv7CCc4g6kzfNmPC6sL7mCOO9Kw%2BFupkiYfqHBrCY52MepKIu2cm75UzsXHOsg67hALh41xQ4y5QzkXbQQPi4gNzcS3ZR2NcISIDmDfE6jjyYAVloxc5xDrBwupTYxFjzGX3Vow0xdFzgAHk/hlJAKGf6TFVKXk9PJRSyl7RaXzMlVEYRaAQmzsqVU3INRMG0Z6a43SDSTVoLLNadYWEIXYTo9U75m4gi6RCaezYkxgNPpAswkhdlHGuBhQ6RwGCoEDBsZIBAby9WQcWDCMigHalomBVZ4QTmpz6WqQZwyjCjMIKfSZHSaIgTAr0lUXyCxMA6eyFwewQWQiuLcB4zw3ifG%2BL8AE4cQSgRxbivF%2BKCWEqJcSkleLkp0QpFSGkkhJDfNnP2BAuy2QcipfHVwjhnSYFYHKZhji2GuEGRaWc4FzxqXtAADWuZ3EYJo8DIFCT9UyKMpJiE8PHGCzpQ53hPhA8%2B0CrJwOOUggsb9wL6PuRvPeoJMEAVsbuVhEplWqrYWSEE6zhzdLeSjBshh7T4xVV4NhtrLhhHtCwHxh0pWxIYo0sF/T1SQotHShJwA/njLEEs4NvVJX4l2UwBNCgFBMGADpGlC1VAVq1UcHNrg83qiYIW4tpa9lQ18m2qtNbBU1UpJ/Ctqh%2BwBrVSFfZkUTmoD9TSkKbbfIDudVYo4VpF0dtpHWpURaS27MOVMy%2BI7t2SBMRfSQ%2Bbw2No3WWqGi6rQtuDdraqaBwwSlpEcPtj78QExcLQKtm1Vh%2BtzW%2B6dr7XDvoOJ%2BrBt7vI/sAwuxdUHDwfq/fg%2B9v7a1vsvfuldb64MgZkfvO8MqHDyvdSjVQ6ME0NCFSmwqkgCI0q3cOmlZaaUANifhuVCq%2BYo18qRrtH8Oy7K4DR6Qh7GOSGY9rWVhHD5Ks2VabjibLSUcPFKGUOlyo0q4BWwTdG%2BHEEmtNfEMCQoplZGpmlEtzN7LLTdGizHerfofRhoDGiID9pyY5w91T9nuZI%2B5rD6BQNI3s8hp9zmZ1ub/UB3ZnmaVQa475/B8GwMeTvZB3zKS0lWnNbbdzUXD1Qdk/F6qiWb0eQk%2Bx0BKN834345ui1gWGgEfK0fTZ0RSNVZ3Qxyzkgt0IZSw5iLRxWuFYtMV/q95SkVKqUcOkDBRKaW5OEVQ9pPXcliOmXccrCC0C4yxDYTFWxSeIHpOziHUsDa7YuXZQ95JvNq%2BTXZo7TkTqE7sn1ggXyDtYegO7UEUNOYS9hpLeHTv9b%2B%2Bx31tILuUau21G70daMYXo5IUduykdvftJgT7BpvsI7ilDYbIBRu4fFtOdmDy/gcGWLQTgH5eC%2BA4FoUgqBOC1osBYhQqx1jw%2B2DwUgBBNCU%2BWPrEAH4tT9g0OyAALEkFMCRJcfi4LLrUkv9CcEl7wFgIuNCkHp4z5nHBeAKBANr/nDPKekDgLAGAiAapGjoHEcglA0B2/oPEYAAnpA0FoOMo3EBogC9INEMIjRfKcF587tgggykMG2wHrA4ajDiDN6QfA%2BZ1JSUwEb5PgZlLhk2Iz0N1QA/dOiJNYgvl3BYDD7wAOmvuDm6oAYYACgABqeBMBiTKVnavMhBAiDEOwATvf5BKDUAH3QkwDBGBQFYKw%2Bg8DRCN5AZYtVahZ5wjhIkxFTBs4sJIDQuEynbFwsnPagg2M4QAOpiFoLhS/gZSz5qv3EYgJBDevnUk4CALhxi%2BEmCEWYUocoPINIDIAQX/EAgoTIPoIAwYSYWwFpLoaYCA%2BAj/WoboJoGAgYeIeA5AjwVoPQGVTAwA7AiQZYDnNYDYPQUsTATYHgKnGnOnAPfXVQfwFMHCFMSXI4YAZAeVATfsfdCAVnSwCwEKXAQgc%2BHYSYabVAF3OIC%2BHnRYGvAXWmLSJgLAeIQ6UgYXLgDQbXanDgdXUgTXD8bXXXXgfXQ3Y3PnFQi3a3CAJAH9UcR3TsOQnAoIfASBPQfgPvUQcQQIHwkfFQdQZPMSSaZIWwgw2nHXZgzgMpcMUceSY4Vg9gzg7g3g/CLgAQgqdwNwhQ9WZQs3VQrlDQygIXCQPQ1XQwjXLXGI5PSwmwaw03LQWmYXSXSQfsBILUFMUwrgbYDQD8SXfwfovsKo7YJg%2BozgQolohgjgSQGo3Qsw2Ig3Gwoo5YDPYgdIJwSXIAA%3D%3D)

```c++20
#ifndef META_STRING_H_INCLUDED
#define META_STRING_H_INCLUDED

#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

namespace meta
{

template <std::size_t N>
struct string;

constexpr auto to_string(const auto& input) { return string(input); }

constexpr auto concat(const auto&... input) { return string(to_string(input)...); }

template <std::size_t N>
struct string
{
    char elems[N];

    // string() = delete;
    string() { elems[N - 1] = '\0'; } // used for CTAD guide for tuples. can't we avoid object construction there?

    constexpr string(const char (&s)[N])
    {
        std::copy_n(s, N, this->elems);
    }

    constexpr string(const string<N> (&s))
    {
        std::copy_n(s.elems, N, this->elems);
    }

    constexpr string(const std::array<char, N> (&s))
    {
        std::copy_n(s.data(), N, this->elems);
    }
    
    template <std::size_t... Ni>
    constexpr void _copy(const string<Ni> (&... input))
    {
        auto pos = elems;
        ((pos = std::copy_n(input.elems, Ni - 1, pos)), ...);
        *pos = 0;
    }

    constexpr string(const auto&... input) requires (sizeof...(input) > 1)
    {
        std::invoke([this](const auto&... s) constexpr { this->_copy(s...); }, to_string(input)...);
    }

    template <template <typename...> typename container, typename... T>
    constexpr string(const container<T...>& input)
    {
        std::apply([this](const auto&... s) constexpr { this->_copy(to_string(s)...); }, input);
    }

    constexpr auto operator + (const auto& rhs) const
    {
        return concat(*this, rhs);
    }

    constexpr operator const char* () const { return elems; }
};

template<std::size_t N> string(const char (&)[N])
    -> string<N>;

template<std::size_t N> string(const std::array<char, N>& input)
    -> string<N>;

string(const auto&... input)
    -> string<((sizeof(to_string(input).elems) - 1) + ... + 1)>;

template<template <typename...> typename container, typename... T> string(const container<T...>& input)
    -> string<((sizeof(to_string(T()).elems) - 1) + ... + 1)>; // TODO: avoid constructing object here


inline namespace meta_string_literals {

template<string ms>
inline constexpr auto operator"" _ms() noexcept
{
    return ms;
}

} // inline namespace meta_string_literals

} // namespace meta

#endif // META_STRING_H_INCLUDED

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// #include "meta_string.h"
#include <iostream>

template<meta::string str>
struct X
{
    static constexpr auto value = str;
    operator const char* () { return str.elems; }
};

template <auto value>
constexpr inline auto constant = value;

int main()
{
    using namespace meta::meta_string_literals;


    X<"a message"> xxx;
    X<"a massage"> yyy;
    X<meta::concat(xxx.value, " is not ", yyy.value)> zzz;
    X<"a message"_ms + " is " + "a massage"> zzz2;

    std::cout << xxx << std::endl;
    std::cout << yyy << std::endl;
    std::cout << zzz << std::endl;
    std::cout << zzz2 << std::endl;


    static constexpr auto x = meta::string("1"_ms, "22");
    static constexpr auto y = meta::concat("11", "22");
    static constexpr auto z = meta::string(std::tuple{"1xx1"_ms, std::array<char, 6>{"2qqq2"}});

    std::cout << sizeof(x.elems) << ": " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(y.elems) << ": " << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(z.elems) << ": " << z << std::endl;

    static constexpr auto a = "1"_ms;
    static constexpr auto b = a + "22"_ms;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    // TODO: Can't it be implicitly forced to constexpr?
    std::cout << meta::string("this one "_ms, "is not ", "constant evaluated"_ms) << std::endl;
    std::cout << constant<meta::string("this one "_ms, "is ", "constant evaluated"_ms)> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want this to convert to a `std::string_view`, as well as `char*`. It’s becoming common to accept `std::string_view` as the common denominator of all string formats.

Comment: I find the _name_ confusing.  A fixed-buffer string is not a "meta string".  Also, I find it especially handy to have such a thing that implicitly converts to `string_view`, in implementing things like a variadic concatenate-everything function, that avoids heap allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more messy than I would prefer, partly because of limitations in C++, partly because you have a constructor that takes a container as an argument. So I don't see another way to do it, just small things that could be improved here and there.

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

It is almost never necessary to write `this->` in C++. I would remove its use everywhere.

## `to_string()` is not necessary

I see you have a free function `to_string()` to ensure you can cast something to a `string` with a different `N` than is used in the templated code you are in, and also to "escape" the deduction guides.
This is not a bad approach, but it might not be necessary to use it.

Inside `class string` you can avoid calling `to_string(input)` by writing `meta::string(input)`.

In the deduction guides it is harder to work around this, you can't just write `meta::string(input).elems`. But see below for a possible solution that also gets rid of the default constructor.

I would be OK with leaving it as you wrote it though, but if it is only intended to be used as a helper function for `struct string`, consider wrapping it inside a `namespace detail` to signal it should not be used by external code directly.

## Unnecessary use of `std::invoke()`

You don't need `std::invoke()` at all, the constructor that uses it can just be rewritten as:

```
constexpr string(const auto&... input) requires (sizeof...(input) > 1)
{
    _copy(to_string(input)...);
}
```

## Make `_copy()` `private`

The member function `_copy()` is just a helper function used by the constructors, so it should be made `private`. I would also remove the leading underscore from the name of this function, as some uses of leading and double underscores in identifiers are [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), and the simplest way to avoid any issues is to avoid *all* leading and double underscores.

## Consider adding `size()` and other `const` member functions from `std::string`

I noticed the `sizeof(to_string(input).elems)` in the deduction guides, and I thought that looked a bit awkward; if there was a `size()` member function it would be nicer to be able to write `to_string(input).size()`. Unfortunately, even with a `static constexpr size()` function, this is not considered a constant expression, so that won't compile. But it will make some of your example usage cleaner:

```
meta::string x(...);
std::cout << x.size() << ": " << x << '\n';
```

You might consider other `const` member functions from `std::string` as well, like `empty()`, `data()`, `operator[]` and so on, to make it a better drop-in replacement for `const std::string`s.

## Deleting the default constructor

To be able to delete the default constructor, you need to avoid default constructing `meta::string`s. That means you can't use `to_string(T())` if `T` is a `meta::string`. There is a very simple solution here, just use `sizeof(T)`:

```
template<template <typename...> typename container, typename... T> string(const container<T...>& input)
    -> string<((sizeof(T) - 1) + ... + 1)>;
```

The drawback, as user17732522 mentioned, is that it doesn't seem to work when constructing a `meta::string` with nested `std::tuples`.

## Forcing constant evaluation of rvalue

I don't think this is possible. At the same time I don't understand why the compiler wouldn't be able to optimize this at compile time, even without using `constexpr`.

## Avoid using `std::endl`

Prefer using [`\n` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary and hurts performance.

Comment: `this->` isn't required in the lambda either.

Comment: `sizeof(T)` is probably not correct in all situations. It is not entire clear what types are supposed to be allowed, but it could for example be another `std::tuple`.

Comment: Personally I was impressed by how @G. Sliepen spotted this-> usage inside of a lambda. Testing out different compilers/versions/flags(-O, -pedantic, e.t.c.) I stumbled into many edge cases, and found out that's the only way to make it always ("cross")compile is to use this-> inside of a lambda.
In general I don't mind a little more verbosity here and there (like this-> inside constructors) if it imposes a bit more readability. Remember 20 years back, during the MFC era, one might write m_elems.

Comment: sizeof(T) is the one particular case I'm trying to avoid at any cost, due to being very cautious with alignment, padding and "structure packing". It can drive us into classical shoot yourself problem very easily. If we can avoid it using meta-programming techniques we should. I will append a modified version of the code with all of the suggestions integrated soon. As imo @G. Sliepen's answer is clearly a solid and throughout analysis and should be accepted.

Comment: As for `sizeof(T)`, I don't think it is a problem for any of the types you are able to support at compile time, but I might be wrong. I strongly suggest you post the modified version of the code as a new question on Code Review, so it can be reviewed on its own. You can add a link to the new question in this post.

Answer (score 2):

- We are in unevaluated context here.

  ```cpp
  // TODO: avoid constructing object here
  template<template <typename...> typename container, typename... Ts>
  string(const container<Ts...>& input)
  -> string<((sizeof(to_string(Ts()).elems) - 1) + ... + 1)>;
  ```

  You can replace `Ts()` by `std::declval<Ts>()`.

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P8f1jd8aT)
- ```cpp
  // TODO: Can't it be implicitly forced to constexpr?
  std::cout << meta::string("this one "_ms, "is not ", "constant evaluated"_ms) << std::endl;
  ```

  `constexpr` is evaluated at compile-time only in constant expression.
  Optimization can do its jobs though (and `constexpr` might be a good hint).

  By applying `consteval`, you might got an error here.